# Pandas DF: Create New Col by removing last word from of existing column

Tags: python, pandas, string, list

This should be easy, but I'm stumped.
I have a df that includes a column of `PLACENAMES`. Some of these have multiple word names:

```
Able County
Baker County
Charlie County
St. Louis County
```

All I want to do is to create a new column in my df that has just the name, without the "county" word:

```
Able
Baker
Charlie
St. Louis
```

I've tried a variety of things:

```
1. places['name_split'] = places['PLACENAME'].str.split()
2. places['name_split'] = places['PLACENAME'].str.split()[:-1]

3. places['name_split'] = places['PLACENAME'].str.rsplit(' ',1)[0]
4. places = places.assign(name_split = lambda x: ' '.join(x['PLACENAME].str.split()[:-1]))
```

1. Works - splits the names into a list `['St.','Louis','County']`
2. The list splice is ignored, resulting in the same list `['St.','Louis','County']` rather than `['St.','Louis']`
3. Raises a ValueError: `Length of values (2) does not match length of index (41414)`
4. Raises a TypeError: `sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found`

I've also defined a function and called it with .assign():

```
def processField(namelist):
  words = namelist[:-1]
  name = ' '.join(words)
  return name

places = places.assign(name_split = lambda x: processField(x['PLACENAME]))
```

This also raises a TypeError: `sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found`

This seems to be a very simple goal and I've probably overthought it, but I'm just stumped. Suggestions about what I should be doing would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Using [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)?

Comment: In `places['PLACENAME'].str.split()[:-1]`, the `[:-1]` indexes the column, not the list in the cells.

Comment: if you take option 3 and add `.str[0]` instead of just `[0]` at the end it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply [`Series.str.rpartition`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rpartition.html) function:

```
places['name_split'] = places['PLACENAME'].str.rpartition()[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to remove the last word and the preceding spaces:

```
places['new'] = place['PLACENAME'].str.replace(r'\s*\w+$', '', regex=True)

# or
places['new'] = place['PLACENAME'].str.replace(r'\s*\S+$', '', regex=True)

# or, only match 'County'
places['new'] = place['PLACENAME'].str.replace(r'\s*County$', '', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
          PLACENAME        new
0       Able County       Able
1      Baker County      Baker
2    Charlie County    Charlie
3  St. Louis County  St. Louis
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BOstWh/1)